# UIScrollView Always Bounces back to Top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've seen a couple of other posts on this, and have attempted to implement their suggestions, but I'm still having the same problem. I have a `UIScrollView` the contains a `UIContentView` that in turn contains various labels and a `UIWebView`. The content scrolls well enough, but it's too long for the screen (by design - that's why I am using a scroll view). As my finger slides to the top of the screen, I need to let go and move my finger to the bottom to continue scrolling. The instant that I let go of the screen, the content bounces right back to the top, thereby negating the scrolling that I have done. This makes it impossible to see the remaining information farther down.

I know that my `UIContentView` has a height that is greater than the maximum y-value of the last object. I verified this with some NSLog statements to print out what the last y value is. What else might I be missing? I've made many other UIScrollViews work, so I don't know what I am overlooking here.

Thanks!

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Assuming that `contentView` has a fixed size, and isn't being autoresized or changed by auto-layout, then you can put the line

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method.

The `layoutIfNeeded` line serves no purpose and should be removed.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't working. As soon as I move that line into `viewDidLoad` I lose all scrolling ability entirely. The view won't move at all.

Comment: My debugging strategy for these kinds of things is to put a button on the screen, and NSLog the `scrollView.frame`, `scrollView.contentSize` and `contentView.frame` in response to the button press.  That should tell you everything you need to know, and guarantees that all of the layout code has had a chance to finish before the sizes are printed.